# Read space delimited text file into array of hashes [Perl]

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have text file that matches the following format:

```
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

And I need to read it into a data structure in perl that will allow me to sort and print according to any of those columns.

From left to right the columns are `process_id`, `memory_size`, `cpu_time` and `program_name`.

How can I read a text file with formatting like that in a way that allows me to sort the data structure and print it according to the sort?

My attempt so far:

```
my %tasks;

sub open_file{
  if (open (my $input, "task_file" || die "$!\n")){
  print "Success!\n";
  while( my $line = <$input> ) {
    chomp($line);
    ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split( /\s/, $line, 4);
    $tasks{$process_id} = $process_id;
    $tasks{$memory_size} = $memory_size;
    $tasks{$cpu_time} = $cpu_time;
    $tasks{$program_name} = $program_name;
    print "$tasks{$process_id} $tasks{$memory_size} $tasks{$cpu_time} $tasks{$program_name}\n";
}
```

This does print the output correctly, however I can't figure out how to then sort my resulting `%tasks` hash by a specific column (i.e. process_id, or any other column) and print the whole data structure in a sorted format.

Comment: Would a solution using an array of arrays be useful or you need a hash?

Comment: Totally open to an array of arrays

Comment: With /usr/bin/sort from GNU coreutils: `sort -k1 -n so-56493032.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing the values under keys that are equal to the values. Use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) to inspect the structure:

```
use Data::Dumper;
# ...
print Dumper(\%tasks);
```

You can store the pids in a hash of hashes, using the value of each column as the inner key.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

my @COLUMNS = qw( memory cpu program );
my %sort_strings = ( program => sub { $a cmp $b } );

my (%process_details, %sort);
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($process_id, $memory_size, $cpu_time, $program_name) = split;
    $process_details{$process_id} = { memory  => $memory_size,
                                      cpu     => $cpu_time,
                                      program => $program_name };
    undef $sort{memory}{$memory_size}{$process_id};
    undef $sort{cpu}{$cpu_time}{$process_id};
    undef $sort{program}{$program_name}{$process_id};
}

say 'By pid:';
say join ', ', $_, @{ $process_details{$_} }{@COLUMNS}
    for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %process_details;

for my $column (@COLUMNS) {
    say "\nBy $column:";
    my $cmp = $sort_strings{$column} || sub { $a <=> $b };
    for my $value (sort $cmp keys %{ $sort{$column} }
    ) {
        my @pids = keys %{ $sort{$column}{$value} };
        say join ', ', $_, @{ $process_details{$_} }{@COLUMNS}
            for @pids;
    }
}

__DATA__
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

But if the data aren't really large and the sorting isn't time critical, just sorting the whole array of arrays by a given column is much easier to write and read:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };
use warnings;

use enum qw( PID MEMORY CPU PROGRAM );
my @COLUMN_NAMES = qw( pid memory cpu program );
my %sort_strings = ((PROGRAM) => 1);

my @tasks;
push @tasks, [ split ] while <DATA>;

for my $column_index (0 .. $#COLUMN_NAMES) {
    say "\nBy $COLUMN_NAMES[$column_index]:";
    my $sort = $sort_strings{$column_index}
        ? sub { $a->[$column_index] cmp $b->[$column_index] }
        : sub { $a->[$column_index] <=> $b->[$column_index] };
    say "@$_" for sort $sort @tasks;
}
__DATA__
...
```

You need to install the [enum](http://p3rl.org/enum) distribution.

Comment: Thanks for this - I am getting a compilation error, says bareword PROGRAM not allowed?

Comment: Actually I turned off strict and it works, thank you. Do you know how to sort on program_name alphabetically?

Comment: Turning off strict is unwise. My program already sorts by program name alphabetically, you just need to install [enum](http://p3rl.org/enum) for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't figure out how to then sort my resulting `%tasks` hash by a specific column

You can't sort a hash. You need to convert each of your input rows in a hash (which you're doing successfully) and then store all of those hashes in an array. You can then print the contents of the array in a sorted order.

This seems to do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @cols = qw[process_id memory_size cpu_time program_name];

@ARGV or die "Usage: $0 [sort_order]\n";

my $sort = lc shift;

if (! grep { $_ eq $sort } @cols ) {
  die "$sort is not a valid sort order.\n"
    . "Valid sort orders are: ", join('/', @cols), "\n";
}


my @data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my %rec;
  @rec{@cols} = split;
  push @data, \%rec;
}

if ($sort eq $cols[-1]) {
  # Do a string sort
  for (sort { $a->{$sort} cmp $b->{$sort} } @data) {
    say join ' ', @{$_}{@cols};
  }
} else {
  # Do a numeric sort
  for (sort { $a->{$sort} <=> $b->{$sort} } @data) {
    say join ' ', @{$_}{@cols};
  }
}

__DATA__
1 4730 1031782 init
4 0 6 events
2190 450 0 top
21413 5928 1 sshd
22355 1970 2009 find
```

- I've used the built-in `DATA` filehandle to make the code simpler. You would need to replace that with some code to read from an external file.
- I've used a hash slice to simplify reading the data into a hash.
- The column that you want to sort by is passed into the program as a command-line argument.
- Note that you have to sort the last column (the program name) using string comparison and all other columns using numeric comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This decides how to sort using the first argument the script receives.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open my $fh, '<', 'task_file';
my @tasks;
my %sort_by = (
    process_id=>0,
    memory_size=>1,
    cpu_time=>2,
    program_name=>3
);
my $sort_by = defined $sort_by{defined $ARGV[0]?$ARGV[0]:0} ? $sort_by{$ARGV[0]} : 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    push @tasks, [split /\s+/, $_];
}
@tasks = sort {
    if ($b->[$sort_by] =~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {
        $b->[$sort_by] <=> $a->[$sort_by];
    } else {
        $a->[$sort_by] cmp $b->[$sort_by];
    }
} @tasks;
for (@tasks) {
    say join ' ', @{$_};
}
```

Comment: This seems to print perfectly but do you know how to make the sort alphabetical?

Comment: Hmm sorry it still seems to be printing non-alphabetically?

Comment: Ok, I have made the change but it is still printing incorrectly

Comment: @DavideLorino Are you passing the program_name argument to the script?

Comment: Yes I have specified argument 3 in the sort

Comment: @DavideLorino You should run the program like this `perl stack.pl program_name` or `./stack.pl program_name` if you give it execute permission.